# Rectangle on Fancy Footer

Tags: fancyhdr

how could we perform the following footer using `fancyhdr` package? The rectangle behind page number could be with rounded only in its bottom-right section. I tried using the boxes environments, but they couldn't align with the bottom rule.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `tcolorbox`, using removed frames and placing nodes for the `Left` and `Middle` footer, the `page corner` is done with a `boxed title` style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[verbose]{geometry}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
    frame hidden,
    attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight+0.1pt,xshift=1.25pt},
    borderline north={1pt}{0pt}{yellow},
    boxed title style={sharp corners=north,arc=2mm,frame hidden,colback=yellow,sidebyside},
    coltitle=black,
    title={Page | \thepage},
    interior hidden,
    underlay={\node[below,xshift=10mm] (A) at (interior.north west) {Footer Left};
      \node[below] (C) at (interior.north) {Footer Middle};
    }
    ]
  \end{tcolorbox}
}
}
```

[image]